# Zabbix maintenance using Ansible

Tags: ansible, zabbix

I would like to use the [`zabbix _maintenance` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/zabbix_maintenance_module.html).

But I want to send the `host_groups` as an extra var so I can put multiple host groups in maintenance.

The problem I faced is that the `host_group` needs a list of items and I can't understand how to write the role so it will run over a list given to it by the extra var

I tried :

```
- name: maintenance
   zabbix_maintenance:
    name: Pause
    host_groups:
      - "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - { 'zabbix_hosts_groups' }
    state: "{{ zabbix_state }}"
    server_url: http://zabbix.XXX.com
    login_user: YYY
    login_password: XXX
    minutes: 90
    desc: "Paused-for-dep"
```

and running it:

```
 ansible-playbook -i 'localhost,' --connection=local zabbix-maintenance.yml -e '{"zabbix_hosts_groups":"Test1","Test2"}' -e 'zabbix_state=present
```

Comment: So the question is why you don't get a shell prompt after pressing Enter? Because the quotes in the command don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically correct task definition would be:

```
- name: maintenance
  zabbix_maintenance:
    name: Pause
    host_groups: "{{ zabbix_hosts_groups }}"
    state: "{{ zabbix_state }}"
    server_url: http://zabbix.XXX.com
    login_user: YYY
    login_password: XXX
    minutes: 90
    desc: "Paused-for-dep"
```

I don't understand the problem description though. "*Jenkins*"??? "*How to write the role*"??? Please at least learn the vocabulary required to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks for "Jenkins" remark - just an honest mistake, I corrected the question.

Comment: I'm trying to use Ansible and send multiple "host_groups" to the role, using extra vars, that's basically my question.

Comment: When using this syntax, I managed to add mutiple host groups by running: ansible-playbook -i 'localhost,' --connection=local zabbix-maintenance.yml -e '{"zabbix_hosts_groups":"Test1","Test2"}' -e 'zabbix_state=present

Answer (score 0):

I use ansible module [zabbix_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/zabbix_host_module.html). There is an attribute *link_templates*. But it removes all groups which are linked to your host before. 
I have not managed this yet. So now I use this to add common templates, and then handly link required templates in Zabbix GUI.

Check this repo, maybe you'll find some helpful: [igogorevi4:Ansible](https://github.com/igogorevi4/Ansible)